# Background running app and user notifications.

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I'm making an app that tracks user location. The idea is when a user reaches certain destination, user's iPhone will vibrate and notification will appear on the screen. I also want to keep app running in background when user locks his phone. 
So the questions are:

1. How to keep an app to run in background?
2. How to send a notification with vibration feedback?

Comment: Check :
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319159/local-notification-vibrate-until-user-action
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276351/make-iphone-vibrate-on-local-notification

Comment: You should use region monitoring using CLRegions.
It will allow you to start up the app even if it is terminated.

Comment: @DatForis Thanks! I've faced a problem that didEnterRegion is not firing at all, but didDetermineState shows that my location is ".inside" of region. Can you suggest possible solution?

Comment: Why yes of course, you have to set the `notifyOnEntry` property of the region as true. This will make the method fire once the event happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the Geofencing in your application. You can use [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial) demo. Also checkout [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) for more information.

Application will notify you when you are in region. So you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use geofencing with google maps sdk? Because I already have a big chunk of code for google maps.

Comment: Nupp. As its apple own feature and its not releated to Map. So we cannot use with google maps.